# How do I mass update values quickly in an efficient query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-update, where-clause

I have 3 tables that contain same column, `Report Year`

I would like to update any Report years that don't have a description. For example, looking at the sample data below, you can see some years don't have any suffix such as 6+6 or 7+5.

Those years that don't have suffixes and are just standalone (i.e. 2020, 2021, etc.), I would like to add a suffix to them "LTP", so they would become like '2020 LTP', '2021 LTP', etc...
Those that are standalone years BUT start with characters, such as BP19, SHOULD NOT BE UPDATED!

pseudo query:

```
UPDATE table1, table2, table3
SET 
    [Report Year] = [Report Year].append(' LTP')
WHERE
    [Report Year].count < 5;
```

I am using count as condition in my pseudo-code as thats the only way I can think of making the query smart enough to recognize what year has a suffix and what doesn't so that it can append the suffix 'LTP' accordingly. If there is a better way to do this, I'd love to see it :)

Sample values in the Report Year column:

Table1 (This has Report Year as a Primary Key, hence Unique/Distinct values only):

```
Report Year
2020 5+7
BP19
2020
2020 6+6
2020 7+5
2021
2022 4+8
2022 
2022
```

Table2:

```
Report Year
2020
2020
2020
2020 6+6
2021
2022 4+8
2022 BP
2022
2020 6+6
2020
2020 6+6
2021
2022 4+8
2022
2022 
2022
```

Table3:

```
Report Year
2020 5+7
2020 5+7
2020
2020
BP19
2020
2020 6+6
2020 7+5
2021
2022 4+8
2022 
2022
2020 6+6
2020 6+6
2020 7+5
2021
2022 4+8
2022 
2022
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pseudo-code translates as four `update` statements:

```
update table1
set [Report Year] = concat([Report Year], ' LTP')
where len([Report Year]) = 4;

update table2
set [Report Year] = concat([Report Year], ' LTP')
where len([Report Year]) = 4;

update table3 ...

update table4 ...
```

The logic is to identify records whose report year is 4 characters only, and then append string "LTP". Each of the 4 table is indenpendent from the others, so running 4 queries is the correct approach.

---

If you want to filter on report years that contain only digits rather than made of 4 characters, then use `not like` and pattern matching:

```
where [Report Year] NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

This phrases as: the report year should not contain any non-digit character.

Comment: i see! and is counting the characters the only way to do this? i like to think of several approaches so want to check if this situation counting the characters is really the only way to accomplish this :)

Comment: @Cataster: for your use case, it looks like a relevant approach. Otherwise you need to describe which logic you want.

Comment: actually, there is a slight problem. we have other years, such as BP19, BP20, etc. and since they are 4 characters in length, they will be counted too. I dont want to count them. i only want to count the years. is there a way we can add more logic so that it avoids the years that start with BP, or generally those that start with a character, not number?

Comment: @Cataster: I updated my answer to filter on all-digits report years only.

Comment: btw, what is the opposite of concat in sql? lets say i wanna revert back these changes, would it be replace()?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the `[Report Year]` column only contains 4 digit years without suffixes, you could test to make sure the 4 characters begin with either 1 or 2, and the remaining 3 are [0-9].  Something like this

```
update table1
set [Report Year] = concat([Report Year], ' LTP')
where [Report Year] like '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]';

update table2
set [Report Year] = concat([Report Year], ' LTP')
where [Report Year] like '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]';

update table3 ...

update table4 ...
```